# Z-index поверх родителя

Tags: html, css

Можно ли внутренний блок показывать поверх родителя с помощью z-index?

```css
.itemtov {
  z-index: 100;
}
.hideblock {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  bottom: -1px;
  left: -1px;
  right: -1px;
  bottom: -47px;
  border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
  border: 1px solid #467797;
  border-top: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 flexitem">
  <div class="itemtov">
    <div class="imgtov">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="img/itemtov.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <a href="" class="name">БОРДЮР ДОРОЖНЫЙ BRAER 
           БР100.30.15, СЕРЫЙ</a>
    <span class="oldprice">420 р/п. м.</span>
    <div class="price">320 <span>Р/ п.м.</span>
    </div>
    <div class="sale">
      -25%
    </div>
    <div class="hideblock">
      <span>Размер</span>
      <a href="" class="likeds">В избранное</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: пример? один элемент в родителе и так поверх него

Comment: сейчас покажу пример

Comment: У меня позиции формируются по сетке бутстрап, блок .hideblock должен перекрывать .itemtov .

Comment: без подключенного бутстрепа непонятно, но тут свиду он перекрывает нормально. у itemtov стоит position relative или absolute? если нет, то ваш блок улетит за его пределы

Comment: relative стоит у него

Comment: Сейчас залью на хостинг и дам ссылку.

Answer (score 1):

Да, если у него задано `position: relative | absolute | fixed;` и если `z-index:` потомка не превышает `z-index:` родителя.